# How to join three tables following the date?

Tags: sqlite

> I have three data tables and they are given below. My first table name is product_table, the second table name is product_purchase_table, and the third table name is product_transfer_table. I'm trying to join these three tables like table name Table After Joint which is given below. My data will be joint once after another following the date like the given Table(Table After Joint).

```
        product_table
row_id  product_id  product_name
 1         101     Accounting Book
```

```
            Product_Purchase_table
row_id  product_id      date     quantity    price
 1        101       2020-10-25     100      1000
 2        101       2020-10-29     200      2000
```

```
             Product_transfer_table
row_id  product_id     date       t_quantity  t_price
1         101        2020-10-26     10       120
2         101        2020-10-27     15       180
3         101        2020-10-30      5        60
```

```
                        Table After Joint
row_id    product_id    product_name        date        quantity    price   t_quantity t_price
1            101      Accounting Book       2020-10-25      100     1000
2            101      Accounting Book       2020-10-26                          10       120
3            101      Accounting Book       2020-10-27                          15       180
4            101      Accounting Book       2020-10-29      200     2000
5            101      Accounting Book       2020-10-30                           5        60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `FULL OUTER` join of `Product_Purchase_table` and `Product_transfer_table` (emulated by `LEFT` joins and `UNION ALL` because SQLite does not support `FULL OUTER` join) and `INNER` join the result to `product_table`

```
SELECT row_number() over (partition by pt.product_id order by t.date) row_id,
       pt.product_id, pt.product_name,
       t.date, t.quantity, t.price, t.t_quantity, t.t_price
FROM product_table pt
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ppt.product_id, ppt.date, ppt.quantity, ppt.price,
         ptt.t_quantity, ptt.t_price
  FROM Product_Purchase_table ppt LEFT JOIN Product_transfer_table ptt
  ON ptt.product_id = ppt.product_id AND ptt.date = ppt.date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ptt.product_id, ptt.date, ppt.quantity, ppt.price,
         ptt.t_quantity, ptt.t_price
  FROM Product_transfer_table ptt LEFT JOIN Product_Purchase_table ppt
  ON ptt.product_id = ppt.product_id AND ptt.date = ppt.date 
  WHERE ppt.product_id IS NULL 
) t ON t.product_id = pt.product_id
ORDER BY pt.product_id, t.date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=43fe6e019a0c586c0a16c23c3e7c3169).
Results:

```
> row_id | product_id | product_name    | date       | quantity | price | t_quantity | t_price
> -----: | ---------: | :-------------- | :--------- | -------: | ----: | :--------- | :------
>      1 |        101 | Accounting Book | 2020-10-25 |      100 |  1000 | null       | null   
>      2 |        101 | Accounting Book | 2020-10-26 |     null |  null | 10         | 120    
>      3 |        101 | Accounting Book | 2020-10-27 |     null |  null | 15         | 180    
>      4 |        101 | Accounting Book | 2020-10-29 |      200 |  2000 | null       | null   
>      5 |        101 | Accounting Book | 2020-10-30 |     null |  null | 5          | 60
```